# Truffle - run script after migrate

Tags: truffle, truffle-migration

Is there a way to automatically run a script (such as copy files from a to b) when the truffle migrate command finishes?

I want to copy the json files from the build/contracts folder into the a folder where my webapp code is.

Currently I use the "truffle develop" command console, soit would be cool, if I could just type "migrate" to for a deployment script to kick in and copy the files.

Comment: Why don't you write a script which calls `truffle migrate` and then copies those json files?

Comment: i don't think that is possible via truffle means of course, but you can write a JS script and run it with node or just in any kind of language you want.

Comment: I can't run truffle migrate because it won't work on my office workstation. I can run the migrate command from inside the Truffle development console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truffle scripts are executed in stages. So you can create an additional state that is executed last (`migrations/9_copy_artifacts.js`). That will run after all previous stages have completed, so you will be sure the contract's artifacts will be in the build directory.

Comment: Thanks Ismael, actually that did the trick - worked perfectly - thank you!